# I do not see any information in logs, that my file was open by jsonSlurper in jmeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I am trying just simply open the json file with jsonSlurper and then log the data from the file into the logs. Logs are set to debug level

my code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput


def slurp = new JsonSlurper()
def fil = slurp.parse(new File("C:/path/test.json"))

log.info(fil)
```

it looks, that my file was not parsed or I do not use log.info in correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the log file most probably you will see something like:

> Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.info() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.groovy.json.internal.LazyMap)

all the possible usages of the `log.info()` function are listed in the [JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.html)

so in order to see the "slurped" JSON in the log file you need to cast it to the [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) first like:

```
log.info(fil as String)
```

More information on pre-defined variables in Groovy: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: adding toString() method helped